# PHP validation of form elements created with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

Hopefully the title gets the idea across, but basically, I have a php page that contains a couple of select form items that can get expanded via jquery so the user can add more than one item to their order.

```
<div class="orderSet" id="order1">
<select id="movie1" class="movie" name="movie">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select movie</option>
    <option value="godfather">The Godfather</option>
            blah...blah....
    <option value="titanic">Titanic</option>
</select><br>
<select id="medium1" class="medium" name="medium">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select format</option>
    <option value="dvd">Movie on DVD</option>
    <option value="bluray">Movie on BluRay</option>
    <option value="poster">Original movie poster</option>
</select>
</div>
```

The new div has an id of orderN where N is the number assigned by the jquery code, similarly the same applies for the movie and medium id's. Is there any way to obtain this number so I can create an array of order items? I am fine feeding the number back to the script so the validated page starts with the right number of items.

The script creating these extra divs is

```
$("#add").click(function () {
    var intId = $("#orderItem div").length + 1;
    var orderSet = $("<div class=\"orderSet\" id=\"order" + intId + "\"/>");
    var movie = $("<select id=\"movie" + intID + "\" class=\"movie\"><option value=\"\" disabled selected>Select movie</option><option value=\"godfather\">The Godfather</option>...more options...<option value=\"titanic\">Titanic</option></select><br>");
    var medium = $("<select id=\"medium" + intID + "\" class=\"medium\"><option value=\"\" disabled selected>Select format</option><option value=\"dvd\">Movie on DVD...more options...</select>");
    var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"remove\" />");
    removeButton.click(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    orderSet.append(movie);
    orderSet.append(medium);
    orderSet.append(removeButton);
    $("#orderItem").append(orderSet);
});
```

Comment: So you just want the number of div generated considering addition and  removal of div?

Comment: I think that should do it. I can create an array from there and validate each item in the array. Might be a bit of a long winded process but it should work out. Would be nice to create a dynamic variable name, something like $movie+number but I can work around that.

Comment: Consider using `name="order[]"` as this will create a PHP array when you post the form. You can use `data-line="1"` for simple jQuery referencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First method

Create array `var userSelection = new Array()` on user addition do

```
userSelection.push(intId)
```

on removal do

```
// Find and remove item from an array
var i = userSelection.indexOf(intId);
if(i != -1) {
    userSelection.splice(i, 1);
}
```

---

Second way:

You can maintain the user state in sesisonStorage, create array for addition and subtraction or single array whatever you feel is fine and store it in sessionStorage

```
var addition = new Array();
```

on add click add orderItem to it

```
addition.push(intId ) // intId  generated in your code
sessionStorage.setItem('added', addition)
```

on second addition click

```
sessionStorage.getItem('added').push(intId)
```

Then you can send this across the server in the format required, same thing you can do with removal